# Protection needed on login form with closed shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, bots, web-component

Is protection needed against bots for a form login created in a web component with HTMLElement and having the shadow root defined as closed?
(excerpt:)

```
connectedCallback() {
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'closed'
    });
....
customElements.define('compo-login', CompoLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll still need a protection.

Actually it will depend on how bots are programmed.

For example, a bot based on UX simulation can generate clics and editing:

- click on the (x,y) coordinates (where an input field is)
- enter a login or any text entry
- click on another (x',y') coordinates (where the submit button is).

It's not based on DOM elements but on their predicatable positions on the screen.
This behavior can be recorded easilsy with a free software (e.g. Selenium) with no knowledge in any programming language required.

---

There are also advanced bots based on shape recongnition...

Or bots the just address the server API of your website (ignoring the client code).

**Conlusion**

Maybe some bot won't work, but most of them will still work.